# How to display array data in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dataset like below inside a cell named rolls.

```
[
    "142650",
    "142651",
    "142603",
    "142604"
]
```

I have an array named $rooms, where each room has cell called rolls.

```
@foreach($rooms as $room)
    {{ $room->rolls }}
@endforeach
```

The code above displaying data like below in view

```
["142650", "142651", "142603", "142604", "142605"]
```

But I want to display like below...

```
142650, 142651, 142603, 142604, 142605
```

I have tried this

```
 @foreach($rooms as $room)
   @foreach($room->rolls as $roll)
      {{ $roll }}
   @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

But getting error like below

*Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

Comment: What is the datatype of $room->rolls ? Try dd(gettype($room->rolls))

Comment: It's string, I have created using $table->json('rolls');

Comment: You can't iterate over a string directly. You need to convert it into an array if you want to display it like you've posted in your question. Can you paste the exact output of dd($room->rolls) here.

Comment: "["142650", "142651", "142603", "142604", "142605", "142606", "142607", "142608", "142609", "142610", "142611", "142612", "142613", "142614", "142615", "142616", "142617", "142618", "142619", "142620", "142621", "142622", "142623", "142624", "142625", "142626", "142627", "142628", "142629", "142630", "142631", "142632", "142633", "142634", "142635", "142636", "142637", "142638", "142639", "142640", "142641", "142642", "142643", "142644", "142645", "142646", "142647", "394485", "394486", "394487"] ◀"

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest solution, without changing controller is

```php
@foreach($rooms as $room)
   <h1>{{ $room->name }}</h1>
   @foreach(json_decode($room->rolls) as $roll)
      {{ $roll }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Try not to use `@php` or `<?php ?>` in your blade templates

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have found, I have not changed anything in my controller, this is what I have done in the view.

```
   @foreach($rooms as $room)
       <h1>{{ $room->name }}</h1>
       <?php $rolls = json_decode($room->rolls); ?>
       @foreach($rolls as $roll)
          {{ $roll }}@if(!$loop->last), @endif
       @endforeach
   @endforeach
```